# Invalid initialization error

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a class with a private member `std::set<Segment*> mSegments` and the following method:

```
std::pair<iterator, iterator> getSegments() {
    return boost::tie(mSegments.begin(), mSegments.end());
}
```

and I get the following error:

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Segment*>&` from a temporary of type 
>    `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Segment*>`

I'm not sure how to solve this one. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you should probably be using `make_pair` here instead of `tie`.  The point of `tie` is to allow functions that return tuples to have the return value assigned to multiple values at once.  For example, if `Get3DPoint` returns a `tuple<int, int, int>`, then you could write

```
int x, y, z;
tie(x, y, z) = Get3DPoint();
```

Because of this, `tie` always accepts its parameters by non-`const`reference so that they can be mutated.  In your case, the return values of `begin()` and `end()` are temporaries, so they can't be bound to non-`const` references.

`make_pair` (and `make_tuple`), on the other hand, are designed to take multiple values and package them up into a single `pair` or `tuple` object that can be passed around.  This is what you want to use in your function.  If you change the code to read

```
std::pair<iterator, iterator> getSegments() {
    return std::make_pair(mSegments.begin(), mSegments.end());
}
```

Then your code should compile just fine.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have much experience with `boost::tie` but by looking at the error message I can say that the error is because you are trying to bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Temporaries cannot be bound to references to non-const objects.

For example

```
 Myclass &ref = Myclass(); // ill formed
```

Answer (score 0):

`boost::tie`'s parameters are non-const references, but `begin` and `end` return temporaries. You'd need to store them somewhere for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is declaration of tie:

```
template <class A, class B> tied<A,B> tie(A& a, B& b);
```

And this is declaration of begin (end):

```
iterator begin()
```

This means that begin() returns temporary object (not reference to it) which can't passed to tie.